# Self-signed SSL-certificate

Tags: ios, ssl, ssl-certificate, self-signed

I try to open https link with standard Webbrowser component. SSL-certificate is self-signed. Browser shows nothing, no errors. It's blank screen only. How to make it open site even if SSL-certificate not valid (expired or self-signed certificate)?

PS. Delphi Berlin FMX, iOS simulator 9.3

Comment: The browser will not open an HTTPS link that does not have a valid certificate. If it did, it would defeat the entire purpose of HTTPS, which is to ensure you're connecting to a site whose identity can be verified **using a valid certificate**.

Comment: @KenWhite web browser apps will usually prompt the user whether an unverified certificate should be accepted, in case the user knows something the browser doesn't. I would expect a web browser component to have an event or callback of some kind to allow a containing app to make a similar decision.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Firefox simply refuses to open the site at all if the certificate is invalid. There is no prompt any longer.

Comment: @KenWhite: FireFox does display an error message about it, and it gives you the option of adding a self-signed certificate to its exceptions list so you can then connect

Comment: You have to install the self-signed certificate in iOS.  Alternatively, set up your own CA and install that instead - your certificates will then be trusted rather than untrusted (on the test device).  This isn't really a delphi question.

Comment: Guys did you get a solution for the issue?

Comment: @J, i install certificate to iOS simulator (it's trusted now on this device), but nothing changes. Still see blank screen.